# How do I get a part of the URL to be assigned to a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

the url on my local project is :-

```
http://localhost/mysite/KB/Type-1/General-Article
```

and on server it is:-

```
http://www.mysite.com/KB/Type-1/General-Article
```

from both the urls, I want to fetch the URL part until Type-1 without slash

ie from localhost website address, I want:-

```
http://localhost/mysite/KB/Type-1
```

and from server, I want :-

```
http://www.mysite.com/KB/Type-1
```

How can I do this? Please help ..thanks

**Please note that Type-1 is not a fixed, it wcan change. It can be anything like "Type-2", "User-Articles", etc.**

**Thanks for the answers but will this still work if there is a slash at the end of the URL too?
like this:-
    http://www.mysite.com/KB/Type-1/General-Article/
Please note that the text "KB" in the URL is FIXED.**

Answer (score 2):

try this code,

```
url.Substring(0, url.LastIndexOf("/")-1);
```

**edit:** if you have ending slash, you can use following code

```
url=url.Remove(test1.Length - 1);
url.Substring(0, url.LastIndexOf("/")-1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but will this still work if there is a slash at the end of the URL too? like this:- "http://www.mysite.com/KB/Type-1/General-Article/" Please note that the text "KB" in the URL is FIXED.

Answer (score 2):

since you don't provide enough information only some general idea:

**EDIT 2** - as per comments:

```
string MySubURL = MyURL.SubString ( 0, MyURL.TrimEnd(null).TrimEnd(new char[]{'/'}).LastIndexOf ("/") );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but will this still work if there is a slash at the end of the URL too? like this:- http://www.mysite.com/KB/Type-1/General-Article/ Please note that the text "KB" in the URL is FIXED.

Comment: I am fetching the URL using this string MyURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl; The problem is that on my local it is returning "mysite/KB/Type-1/General-Article
" so the result of your code is not correct for me. How do I get the complete URL from the address bar?

Comment: /mysite/KB/User-Artic  this is what I got as a result

Comment: ok I just added static URL value in the myurl string and still the result is the same

Comment: you don't get the exact URL from the address bar except by using javascript on the client side.

Comment: but I assigned a static value to the MyURL string to test ie http://localhost/mysite/KB/Type-1/General-Article
 and still I am getting the result as http://localhost/mysite/KB/User-Artic

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want whether there is a '/' at the end or not in a single line. It is a bit longer, but it works for all of your outlined requirements.

```
string url = "http://www.mysite.com/KB/Type-1/General-Article";
string seg = url.EndsWith("/") ? url.Substring(0, url.TrimEnd('/').LastIndexOf('/')) : url.Substring(0, url.LastIndexOf('/'));
```

Comment: OP specifically says that "Type-1" can't be expected